# Simple XML over http web service

Tags: python, xml, django, web-services

I have a simple html service, developed in django. 
You enter your name - it posts this, and returns a value (male/female).

I need to ofer this as a web service. I have no idea where to start.

I want to accept a xml request, and provide an xml response - thats it.

Can anyone give ma any pointers - Googling it is difficult when you dont know what your searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Generating non-HTML content](http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter11/) in the django book for instructions.

Basically, it's as simple as this:

```
def get_data(request, xml_data):
    data = parse_xml_data(xml_data)
    return_data = create_xml_blob(data)
    return HttpResponse(return_data, mimetype='application/xml')
```

**Edit:**

You can send a post with xml_data set to the XML string, or you can send an XML request.

Here's some code for sending XML data to a web service, adapted from [this site](http://users.skynet.be/pascalbotte/rcx-ws-doc/postxmlpython.htm):

```
xml_data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>my data here</root>
"""

#construct and send the header

webservice = httplib.HTTP("example.com")
webservice.putrequest("POST", "/rcx-ws/rcx")
webservice.putheader("Host", "example.com")
webservice.putheader("User-Agent", "Python post")
webservice.putheader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"")
webservice.putheader("Content-length", "%d" % len(xml_data))
webservice.endheaders()
webservice.send(xml_data)
```

From django, you'd use `request.raw_post_data` to get at the XML directly.

Comment: I am not worried about generating non-html content. Accepting an xml request is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Send it in a post, with the variable xml_data set to your xml data. Encode in utf-8.

Comment: This probably changed in the time, now it is: 
```return HttpResponse('<xml/>', content_type='text/xml')```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [Piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home), which is framework for exposing Django apps as web services.

Comment: Yeah, definitely +1 for piston